# Where identity server 4 persists reference tokens?

Tags: identityserver4

Let's say user logins and gets access_token ( reference ) back with expiry of 2 hours, during this time frame ID4 was restarted. Will the access_token will be valid at this point ?

(I'm not using Entity Framework) but my own 'IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator' implementation.

If yes how and where ?
If no do you know how to overcome that by ID4 design ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token is a type of `PersistedGrant` that is managed by some implementation of the `IPersistedGrantStore` interface. It isn't well-documented, it's only mentioned in the [Operational Data](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/deployment.html#operational-data) section of the Deployment topic, but it's relatively simple. I don't like Entity Framework and fortunately Identity Server persistence is pretty easy to write yourself (I recently blogged about it [here](https://mcguirev10.com/2018/01/02/identityserver4-without-entity-framework.html)), you just have to implement all of the various stores (plus whatever you want to save in terms of the user's account associated with the basic identity details created after login).

Here is the interface definition: [IPersistedGrantStore](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/release/src/IdentityServer4/Stores/IPersistedGrantStore.cs)

And this is the data it stores: [PersistedGrant](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/release/src/IdentityServer4/Models/PersistedGrant.cs)

You'll have to register your store as a transient service in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddTransient<IPersistedGrantStore, PersistedGrantStore>();
```

Comment: @eugeneK Edited to add the service requirement. Now that I've (mostly) figured out Identity Server and  OIDC I'm trying to help as many others as I can. Their docs are pretty good but there's still a lot going on behind the scenes that gets glossed over. If that got you on the right track, please accept as the answer.